Access rich-text formatting of clipboard contents in human-readable way
When copying things from certain programs such as Microsoft Word, formatting is copied along with the plain text.
If I paste this formatted text somewhere where formatting isn't supported, such as Notepad, only the plain text is pasted.
If I paste it somewhere where it actually is supported, both the text and the formatting appear, with the formatting ALREADY APPLIED.
—————— OBJECTIVE ——————
What I want is something in between. I want to paste the plain text PLUS the formatting itself also AS PLAIN TEXT so that I am able to see what the formatting structure is like.
In other words, I need the formatting to be preserved but NOT applied. The formatting should also be pasted as plain text.
—————— EXAMPLE ——————
If I copy some bolded HTML text, say, example, when I paste it:
It should NOT be like this: example
It should NOT be like this: example
INSTEAD, I NEED THIS: <b>example</b>
I need a solution that works independently of the formatting. Whether it be markdown, rich text, HTML or whatever else, I need the formatting itself to be preserved as plain text.
—————— WHAT I TRIED ——————
Installing Ditto. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to provide direct access to the formatting itself.

If you just want to view the original format of rich text, you can use the software called Freeclipboardviewer to view it.
